# Configuring the sound played when Push Notification is received

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

How can we configure the sound which gets played when an application is in the background and a push notification is received?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the ["The Notification Payload" section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) of [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1).

---

**Example JSON Payload** (adapted from above document):

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    }
}
```

The key you're looking for here is `sound`, it's a string that points to an `aiff`, `caf`, or `wav` file within your bundle.

Comment: What if I have a WAV file. Can I mention that file in the JSON payload?

Comment: Actually, yes. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6 (I've updated my answer to reflect)